# TensorFlow: Error with tf.where()

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am not sure why tf.where() does not work as planned. I want to use the values of `a` where `yt` is less that 5, otherwise use `b`.

```
tf.InteractiveSession()
yt = tf.constant([10,1,10])
a = tf.constant([1,2,3])
b = tf.constant([3,4,5])
tf.where(tf.less(yt,[5]), a, b).eval()
```

Gives the error

```
where() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Can you tell me why I am getting this error?  Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: This codes runs without any errors for me !! tensorflow version 0.12.1

Comment: Oh thanks. Didn't have the proper version

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax for `tf.where()` was changed between TensorFlow 0.10 (when it [took two arguments and returned two outputs](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/math_ops/sequence_comparison_and_indexing#where)) and TensorFlow 0.12+ (it now [takes three tensor arguments and returns a single output](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/where), replacing the former `tf.select()`).

As [Himaprasoon suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148514/tensorflow-error-with-tf-where#comment73374576_43148514), upgrading to the latest version of TensorFlow should fix your problem.