# tensorflow: how to select rows of matrix with condition

Tags: matrix, tensorflow, where-clause

I find similar solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148514/tensorflow-error-with-tf-where). However, this solution makes a binary selection between two matrices based on one condition. What I need to do is to select only the rows that satisfy the condition. How can I achieve this?

I will briefly introduce the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43148514/tensorflow-error-with-tf-where). The example is :

```
tf.InteractiveSession()
yt = tf.constant([10,1,10])
a = tf.constant([1,2,3])
b = tf.constant([3,4,5])
tf.where(tf.less(yt,[5]), a, b).eval()
```

The result will choose a value from `a` if the associated `yt` value is less that 5, and otherwise choose a value from `b`. What I need is to select a value from `a` if `yt<5`, and otherwise do not choose anything.

How can I achieve this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
a[tf.squeeze(tf.where(tf.less(yt,[5]), None, None))
```